# General Relativity Effects Observation in the lab

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, reference-frames, acceleration

Is it possible to observe any General Relativity effects in the lab with relatively simple experiments?

I cannot create any gravity in the lab, but I can create high acceleration (100-1000 g force, maybe even up to 10 000 g, meaning acceleration up to $10^5m/s^2$) or I can rotate something very fast up to 100 000 RPM. Based on the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) this acceleration will lead to some changes due to General Relativity.

For example, in this highly accelerated/rotated reference frame, I can try to see so effects in:

- Electromagnetic field change
- Light propagation change
- Mechanical effects
- etc.

Or this 10 000g/100 000 RPM is too small to notice any General Relativity effects?

Maybe there were some known experiments like this?

Comment: See the [Pound-Rebka experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound–Rebka_experiment) (and links therein), and the underrated [Project GREAT](http://www.leapsecond.com/great2005/).

Comment: As I understand it, GPS would not work without accounting for the GR. Therefore, assuming one's cell phone is an example of a small lab (or, at least, a relay for one), one could say that the GR is tested (successfully) all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember that acceleration is *not* the same as curvature of spacetime. The equivalence principle says only that gravity is indistinguishable from acceleration in a "small enough" region of spacetime, i.e. in the limit as the spacetime volume goes to 0. Sensitive experiments, or ones that run over a large area or long time, can tell the difference. For a trivial example, the direction of gravity near the Earth changes over long distances, and this is very much detectable.

So using centrifuges and the like is not a useful way to test General Relativity (curvature of spacetime) because they do not actually curve spacetime -- they produce acceleration which is *like* gravity in a local area, but they don't actually produce gravity.

Having said that, modern clocks are sensitive enough to directly measure relativistic effects due to Earth's gravity, e.g. time dilation due to gravity can be distinguished between clocks that are less than a meter different in height (see https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2010/09/nist-pair-aluminum-atomic-clocks-reveal-einsteins-relativity-personal-scale ).

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link. I do not mean that I want to create gravity with acceleration. I want to detect any General Relativity effects., For example, the lector here 
https://youtu.be/JRZgW1YjCKk?t=1706 says, that light in the accelerated frame will go by a parabola, but not by a straight line. I mean effects like this.

Or do you mean the lector in this video is wrong?

Comment: In modern usage "general relativity" is the study of curved spacetime, with "special relativity" being the study of flat spacetime. Accelerating reference frames in flat (or nearly flat) spacetime still fall under special relativity. That light follows a parabola in an accelerating reference frame is a geometric inevitability given that it moves in a straight line in flat space. I doubt anyone has bothered to test that. The Sagnac effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect is a feature of rotating reference frames with practical applications. But it's an SR effect, not GR.

Comment: This light going as a parabola in a moving lift will only happen if the lift is moving with acceleration. If the lift is moving at a constant speed it will be a still straight line. This is what I thought is the difference between GR and SR.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Here is the explanation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity)
I asked the wrong question.